# Поправить текст, показываемый новым пользователям под формой ответа

Tags: дефект, локализация, ответы, нет-в-transifex

Если низкоуровневым участником зайти в вопрос, то под формой ответа появляется:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проведенное** → **проведённое**.

В традусёре не нашёл строку.

Comment: Не ленитесь писать предысторию к проблеме, как её повторить, чтобы потом можно было проверить готовность исправления. Строка, скорее всего относится к очередным файлам настроек сайта и доступна к редактированию только КМ.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ добавил. Учту на будущее)

Comment: Блин, снова [эта проблема с отправкой комментария](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324052/339911)...

Comment: Я бы ещё здесь добавил кавычки-ёлочки вокруг имени сайта, букву о между «Просьб помощи», запятую после «на темы», запятую после «Ответов», запятую после «аргументы». Вероятно, убрать запятую после «Также». Предлагаю всё это внести в вопрос, подправить картинку и заголовок с метками :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ чуть позже поправлю)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вообще, лучше бы эту строку в транс запихать.

Comment: Не уверен, вспомните хотя бы про наличие сайта «Русский язык», с которым единая база переводов. Они там как-то уже страдали от «программ, отладки» и чего-то иного SO-подобного.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ поправил.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что мы не ставим кавычки около названия на английском. Но если строка общая для наших сайтов, то тогда ставим.

Comment: @Aer кто «мы» и почему не ставим? В любом случае, речь о фразе «Stack Overflow на русском», которая, как можно заметить, имеет как русские, так и английские слова. Строка, скорее всего уникальна для каждого сайта, но это может подтвердить только КМ.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ под _мы не ставим_ имею в виду традицию, которую с вами обсуждали в седые годы в чате. А SO на русском кавычится, потому что это текст смешанный, как вы правильно заметили.

Comment: @Aer мы, one ... я ничего не понял.